# write $\lvert 10+4i\rvert$ in the form $z=re^{i\theta}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

write $\lvert 10+4i\rvert$ in the form  $z=re^{i\theta}$

I am not sure what to do with the absolute value in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the absolute value is a real number, $\theta = 0$ and $r = \sqrt{ 10^2 + 4^2 } $

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP, the absolute value function changes the $\theta$ value, not the $r$ value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the absolute value is a real number? 10 + 4i is imaginary, why would taking the absolute value of that be a real number?

Comment: $10 + 4i$ is complex, alright. But $ |10 + 4i| $ is the absolute value of $10 + 4i$, and absolute value of any complex number is a real number. That follows from the definition of the absolute value. For a complex number $a + ib$, its absolute value is defined as $ \sqrt { a^2 + b^2 } $ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, which clearly is a real number.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of this definition.. Do you know where I might the proof for this definition?

Comment: You don't prove definitions, but you can see that it is consistent with the definition of absolute value for real numbers.  If $b = 0$, then $|a + bi| = \sqrt {a^2}$ which is the absolute value of $a$, as expected.

Comment: I just can't arrive from $\sqrt{(a+bi)^2}$ to $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Which is something I would expect if I'm told that $|{a+bi}| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: To clarify, I guess my question really is: Am I supposed to be able to get $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ from $\sqrt{(a+bi)^2}$ using algebra?

Comment: No. Obviously $ \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2 } \not = \sqrt{ (a+ib)^2 } $. The definition of modulus of $a+ib$ is not $ \sqrt{ (a+ib)^2 } $. It is $\sqrt { (\text{Real part of } a+ib)^2 + (\text{imaginary part of } a+ib)^2 }$

Answer (score 0):

$$|10+4i|=\sqrt{4^2+10^2}=2\sqrt{29} = 2\sqrt{29}e^{2\pi i n}\qquad n\in \mathbb Z$$